# relation on expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $f \leq M$ on $[0, \infty)$ or even $f(|x|) \leq M$ on $\Omega$ and $f$ is nondecreasing.

How I can show this relation?

$E\{f|x|\} \leq f(t) +\{M- f(t)\}p(|x| \geq t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathsf E\{f(|X|) - f(t)\} = \mathsf E\{(f(|X|) - f(t))\cdot \mathbb 1_{\{|X|\geq t\}}\}+\mathsf E\{(f(|X|) - f(t))\cdot \mathbb 1_{\{|X|< t\}}\} \\ =E_1+E_2.$$
The second summand is non-positive since $f$ is non-decreasing:
$$
E_2\leq 0,
$$
the first summand is bounded by $(M-f(t))\mathbb P(|X|\geq t)$:
$$
E_1=\mathsf E\{(f(|X|) - f(t))\cdot \mathbb 1_{\{|X|\geq t\}}\}\leq
(M-f(t))\mathsf E\{\mathbb 1_{|X|\geq t}\} = (M-f(t))\mathbb P(|X|\geq t).
$$
Therefore
$$
\mathsf E\{f(|X|) - f(t)\}\leq (M-f(t))\mathbb P(|X|\geq t).
$$

Comment: thnx alot NCh you are wonderfull!!

Comment: @nikola
After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).